# How to generate data that fits the normal distribution within each class?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, statistics

Using numpy, I need to produce training and test data for a machine learning problem. The model is able to predict three different classes (X,Y,Z). The classes represent the types of patients in multiple clinical trials, and the model should be able to predict the type of patient based on data gathered about the patient (such as blood analysis and blood pressure, previous history etc.)

From a previous study we know that, in total, the classes are represented with the following distribution, in terms of a percentage of the total patient count per trial:

```
X - u=7.2, s=5.3 
Y - u=83.7, s=15.2 
Z - u=9.1, s=2.3
```

The u/s describe the distribution in N(u, s) for each class (so, for all trials studied, class X had mean 7.2 and variance 5.3). Unfortunately the data set for the study is not available.

How can I recreate a dataset that follows the same distribution over all classes, and within each class, subject to the constraint of X+Y+Z=100 for each record.

It is easy to generate a dataset that follows the overall distribution (the u values), but how do I get a dataset that has the same distribution per each class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have stated is to sample from a mixture distribution. A mixture distribution is just a number of component distributions, each with a weight, such that the weights are nonnegative and sum to 1. Your mixture has 3 components. Each is a Gaussian distribution with the mean and sd you gave. It is reasonable to assume the mixing weights are the proportion of each class in the population. To sample from a mixture, first select a component using the weights as probabilities for a discrete distribution. Then sample from the component. I assume you know how to sample from a Gaussian distribution.